# Appending a new line to a BufferedWriter

Tags: java

I'm trying to write to a text file with each successive call to `writeMore()` writing to a new line if `true` is passed as the last argument. However, the writer keeps writing to the end of the same first line. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
package FileIO;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Buffered_Writer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        String fileName = "myFile.txt";
        String message = "I'm written into the file.";

        File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\" + fileName);
        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not create file!");
        }


        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile, true));
        writer.write(message);

        writeMore("This much more has been written.", myFile, true);

        writer.close();
    }

    public static void writeMore(String message, File file, boolean newLine) throws IOException{

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        if (newLine) {
            writer.append(" \n");
            writer.append(message);
        }
        else {
            writer.append(" " + message);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "However, the writer keeps writing to the end of the same first line." ? Can you show what output you expected and what output you got?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the proper method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()

As per the javadocs

> Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the
>   system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single
>   newline ('\n') character.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use `BufferedWriter.newLine()` method. Additionnaly, do `BufferedWriter` should be closed properly (using `try with resources`):

```
public static void writeMore(String message, File file, boolean newLine) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
        if (newLine) {
            writer.newLine();
            writer.append(message);
        } else
            writer.append(" ").append(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\" + fileName);
```

I can deduce you are on Windows. The Windows line separator is not `\n` (it is `\r\n` but don't hardcode that). Use `System.lineSeparator()` instead. Change

```
writer.append(" \n");
```

to

```
writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
```